# sqlalchemy: AttributeError: type object 'URL' has no attribute 'create'

Tags: python, sql-server, url, sqlalchemy

I have this code:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import ulrllib
import pyodbc as odbc
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

SERVER_NAME = 'H46'
    
DATABASE_NAME = ‘ris’
    
connection_string = f"""
    
Driver = {{SQL Server}};
    
Server = {SERVER_NAME};
    
Database = {DATABASE_NAME};
    
Trusted_Connection = yes;
    
 """
    
     
    
connection_url = URL.create(mssql+pyodbc, query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
    
engine = create_engine(connection_url, module= odbc)
```

I got this error:

How do I solve this please??

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-21-7763d5cbd008> in <module>




----> 1 connection_url = URL.create(mssql+pyodbc, query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})

      2 engine = create_engine(connection_url, module= odbc)

AttributeError: type object 'URL' has no attribute 'create'**
```

Comment: This is obviously not your full code, because `URL` is not defined anywhere.  We can't help without seeing the full code.

Comment: Also, the error message says that `connection_url = URL.create(...)` is on line 1, but that does not match the posted code.  Please show your real code.

Comment: added full query thanks. Also I was running this in Jupyther so URL.create etc. run in one separate paragraph hence line 1..

Comment: I believe the import is supposed to be `from sqlalchemy import URL`.  Why are you using `from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL` ?

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy are you using?  `URL.create` was added in 1,4 I think.

Comment: Because if I use from sqlalchemy import URL it gives me Import error, cannot import URL... Which sqlalchemy version should I use?

Comment: `URL.create` was [added in SQLAlchemy v1.4](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#creating-urls-programmatically), so use any version that's v1.4 or later.